# How do I bounce a cube off a wall and move it in the direction of it's opposite corner

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to move a cube automatically in a random direction and marked the corners with colored points.  What I'm looking to do is to collide with walls and bounce the cube off it's corners toward the opposite point.  I want the cube to stay on a straight course on the x and y plane and behave similar to pong. The cube can rotate so it can collide on the corners.

I tried using the function LookAt and adding force in that direction.  After that i tried using a raycast shooting from the corner of the cube that collided with the wall.  This raycast would shoot in the direction of the opposite corner of the cube and move toward the collision point.  I was thinking that the MoveTowards function would do this.

Here is my bouncing code

```
public class CollideCheck : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isCollided;
    private int direction;
        
    public bool IsCollided
    {
        get { return isCollided; }
    }

    public GameObject YellowMarker { get; private set; }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "RedMarker")
        {
            void RaycastTowardsThing(GameObject other)
            {
                Vector3 raycastDir = other.transform.position - transform.position;
                Physics.Raycast(transform.position, raycastDir);
            }
            RaycastTowardsThing(YellowMarker);
        }
    }
}
```

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collider other)
{
     transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, yellow.transform.position)
}
```

[Here's How the cube bounces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9GVU.jpg)

Comment: Just FTR are you aware that Unity has a collision engine completely built-in that will do this for you?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to do that as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something similar when working on a 'Brick Breaker' game.

To calculate and move the cube in the opposite direction you need to first calculate the heading, or the direction from which the cube came from. This is done by calculating the vector between the two.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collider other)
{
        Vector3 heading = other.transform.position - transform.position;
}
```

Secondly, you need to reverse the vector and calculate the opposite direction.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collider other)
{
        Vector3 heading = other.transform.position - transform.position;
        Vector3 direction = -heading / heading.magnitude;
}
```

Lastly, you will add the direction vector as a velocity to a RigidBody of the cube and multiply it by some speed;

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collider other)
{
        Vector3 heading = other.transform.position - transform.position;
        Vector3 direction = -heading / heading.magnitude;
        rb.velocity = direction * speed;
}
```

I'm not sure if it'll behave the exact same as you want it, but I think I provided a general idea on how to move the cube in the opposite direction.